# Is it possible to update elements of Bootstrap sass

Tags: css, wordpress, bootstrap-sass

I've been tasked to update a few web pages on my companies WordPress website. The new design they've asked for looks like standard Bootstrap Grid functionality.

The website it currently using Bootstrap v3.3.7, seen in the _bootstrap.scss file.

Although this version has a working grid system, it's missing some useful features like:

```
   <div class="col order-last">Last</div>
   <div class="col order-first">First</div>
```

I've added a CDN link to Bootstrap v4.3.1, which makes the **order-last/first** classes work and confirms it's an issue with the bootstrap version. But it overwrites a load of custom styling.

Is it possible to update parts of bootstrap so I can preserve all the styling alterations the previous developer made?

Or, would I have to replace all the bootstrap files for v4.3.1 and try to replicate the previous developers work?

Comment: Could you avoid the problem by using something besides bootstrap for the grid?

Comment: You're opening a can of worms here. If updating bootstrap to a newer version has a high chance of messing up your site due to some modifications made by someone else, I'd avoid that if I were you. As Dylan pointed out, just use something else and save your future self some troubles.

Comment: I appreciate the feedback guys. It doesn't sound like it's worth the hassle for the sake of ordering some columns. I'll look into some alternatives!